# rename file/folder (in selfmade window explorer using listview) via clicking on it

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, contextmenu, file-rename

i want to rename a folder/file on runtime in my window explorer when ever i click on the folder...
i know so far that file.move is used to rename but how to enter file name on runtime?

```
 private void renameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string DestinationFolder = ListviewCurrentFolderPath;
        string CurrentName = DestinationFolder + "FileName";//in filename i want to edit value on run time

        if (Directory.Exists(DestinationFolder))
        {

           // Directory.Move( Path.Combine(new string[] {              DestinationFolder,Path.GetFileName(file) }));
            File.Move( Path.Combine(new string[] { DestinationFolder, CurrentName }));
            PopulateListView(DestinationFolder);

        }
    }
    catch (IOException ios)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ios.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how to enter file name on runtime".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: like we do in window file explorer ..can assign any folder the name we want by renaming it.....i want to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I guess you mean with 'rename at runtime', to rename the label of the listview item which affects in renaming the folder...*

So, first of all you should look at

1. [ListView.LabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.labeledit.aspx)  - to enable the 'renaming'
2. [ListView.BeforeLabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beforelabeledit.aspx)
3. [ListView.AfterLabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.labelediteventhandler.aspx)

I hope this little sample helps you to get the right way :)

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private string destinationFolder;
            private ListView listView1;

            public Form1()
            {
                // Set destinationFolder to MyDocuments - for test
                this.destinationFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

                InitializeComponent();

                this.listView1.Clear();
                foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(destinationFolder))
                {
                    this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Name = dir, Text = Path.GetFileName(dir) });
                }

            }

            private void SetListViewItemName(int index, string name)
            {
                if (this.listView1.Items.Count < index)
                {
                    this.listView1.Items[index].Name = name;
                }
            }

            private string GetListViewItemText(int index)
            {
                if (this.listView1.Items.Count < index)
                {
                    return this.listView1.Items[index].Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                }
            }

            private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    string itemText = GetListViewItemText(e.Item);
                    string sourceDirName = Path.Combine(new string[] { this.destinationFolder, itemText });
                    string destDirName = Path.Combine(new string[] { this.destinationFolder, e.Label });

                    // Rename the old directory.
                    Directory.Move(sourceDirName, destDirName);
                    SetListViewItemName(e.Item, destDirName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Error occured, cancel edit.
                    // Empty text, cancel edit.
                    // There are few more things to check: max pathlength, invalid chars etc.
                    e.CancelEdit = true;
                }
            }

            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // listView1
                // 
                this.listView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
                this.listView1.LabelEdit = true;
                this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
                this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
                this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
                this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
                this.listView1.AfterLabelEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.LabelEditEventHandler(this.listView1_AfterLabelEdit);
                //this.listView1.BeforeLabelEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.LabelEditEventHandler(this.listView1_BeforeLabelEdit);
                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
                this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use the [SaveFileDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx). You may use the `DestinationFolder` for the [FileDialog.InitialDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx).

Comment: i can browse in my file explorer the file that i want to rename and it is placed in destination folder.....now i just want to rename it...i dont want to read the file